# SAML2 Response signing configuration

Tags: itfoxtec-identity-saml2

We are using ITFoxTec to integrate with Azure AD. The Idp has the signing option set to "Sign SAML Assertion". In the saml config i prepare and send with my request, I have used the AuthnResponseSignType as Saml2AuthnResponseSignTypes.SignResponse.

1. It is not clear, if the the ITFoxtec library ignores the setting we send in the configuration and signs solely based on the Idp configuration?
2. If so, is there a setting to validate if the response we get back is signed with the same type as the IDP type?
3. Can we set in the request what the signing type should be and should the SAML response Fail if there is a mismatch in the signing types of the Idp vs request

I also looked at the SamlResponse object to see if there are any settings which will tell me what is the type of signing but could not find any.

Answer (score 0):

Azure AD signs the SAML Authn Response (SAML Assertion). The ITfoxtec Identity SAML library accept the SAML Authn Response if it is signed either on message level, assertion level or on both.
The received SAML Authn Response is only accepted if the signature is valid.

You can signe the SAML Authn Request with ITfoxtec Identity SAML library, but that is something else.

Comment: Once I receive the SAML response, is there a way that i can validate that the response is properly signed?

Comment: The signature is validated when the unbind method is called. If success without an exception, the signatur is valid.